# Create a formatted SpreadSheet with DocumentFormat.OpenXML?

Tags: .net, excel, openxml, xmldocument, openxml-sdk

I want to create a spreadsheet with DocumentFormat.OpenXML.  I've been having a really hard time getting it to work, so I thought I'd ask for help here.

I would like to programmatically create a spreadsheet at runtime to be downloaded from an ASP.net web site.

(1) I want the spreadsheet to contain some rows of data from a SQL Database.  I want the row headers to consist of black text on a yellow background.  I have some string data, which incidently, may contain strings of digits.  I want it to be treated as a string at all times (ie, I don't want 31415926535 to be presented as 3.1415926e10)

(2) I would like to have a 300px x 300px PNG image appear below the last row of data.  The image is saved on the server as hello.png.

What code do I need to write to make (1) and (2) happen?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently done something similar. I believe the best way to accomplish what you need is to first create a template `Excel` spreadsheet. Then, using [`Open XML Productivity Tool`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en), reflect the code needed to create it.

Reading through the limited documentation left me spinning my wheels until I started using the `Productivity Tool`. It does generate some extraneous code but it gets you to the meat and is very helpful.

Comment: Spinning My Wheels?  I think my motor overheated from spinning the my wheels!